# Dúvida com mysqli_fetch_assoc

Tags: php

Fiz um loop usando mysqli_fetch_assoc. Como faço pra saber se estou imprimindo a primeira linha e a última?

```
while ($dados = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    if (É A PRIMEIRA LINHA){
    echo 'imprime algo';
    }
    echo $dados['nome'];
    if (É A ULTIMA LINHA){
    echo 'imprime algo';
    }
}
```

Comment: O que deve acontecer se a primeira e a ultima linha forem a mesma, ou seja, quando houver apenas um registro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A resposta para sua pergunta tomando como base seu script é:

coloque um contador e obtenha o número de linhas do resultado:

```
$numero_de_registros = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$i=1;
while ($dados = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){  

    if ($i==1){
    echo 'imprime algo';
    }

    echo $dados['nome'];

    if ($i==$numero_de_registros){
    echo 'imprime algo';
    }
    $i++;
}
```

> mysqli_num_rows - Obtém o número de linhas em um resultado

OBS: Para o caso de haver somente 1 (um) registro na tabela e não dar `echo` no segundo `if` pode alterar o segundo `if` para `if ($i!=1 && $i==$numero_de_registros){`

Answer (score 2):

Você não precisa saber disso dentro do laço de repetição para obter esse resultado, basta lembrar que tudo o que executar antes do laço sempre estará antes da primeira linha, assim como o que é executado depois estará depois da última linha. Portanto, basta você fazer:

```
echo 'Antes da primeira linha';

while ($dados = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
    echo $dados['nome'];
}

echo 'Depois da última linha';
```

Isso mantém a legibilidade do código e evita ter que avaliar duas expressões lógicas a cada laço. Se quiser evitar que as mensagens apareçam quando não há registros, basta colocar esse trecho de código dentro de um `if` com tal condição.

Comment: se não houver resultados vai dar 2 echos a toa.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo comentei isso na última frase da resposta...

Comment: é verdade, mania de só olhar para o código! reverti o voto rs!